# How to Break on Hyphen Instead of The Last Letter?

Tags: css, word-wrap, word-break

How do you get the browser to wrap on hyphens, when present, instead the last letter on a line of text without spaces?

have not found a difference between word-break and word-wrap.

Here is my live example:

```
<div style="word-break:break-normal;font-size:14px;width:109px;">
    Members-Only Menu
</div>
```

It comes out like this:

```
Members-Onl
y Menu
```

I need it come out like this:

```
Members-
Only Menu
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CSS word-wrap, word-break, and white-space properties, and the `<wbr/>` tag.

Comment: Also, consider using the soft-hyphen character, `&shy;`, instead of a hard hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property `hyphens: manual` would cause the words only to be broken at the hyphen. Unfortunately, this property is not supported in Chrome, Android browser, or anything less than IE10.

[More info here.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/)